# Getting Bootstrap's modal content from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an anchor in a page called `menu.html` and I'm having trouble getting a Bootstrap modal to display data from another page called `Lab6.html`.

**menu.html**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-exl-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li><a href="/emplookup.html">Lookup</a></li>
    <li><a href="/modalexample.html">Modals</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Lab6.html#theModal" data-toggle="modal">Lab 6</a></li><!-- this one -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Lab6.html**

```
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="theModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h1>Lab 6</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            Employee Information
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Title:</div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="title"></div>
              <div class="text-right col-xs-2">First:</div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="firstname"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Phone#</div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="phone"></div>
              <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Email</div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="email"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Dept:</div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="departmentname"></div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-2">Surname:</div>
              <div class="text-left col-xs-4">
                <input type="text" placeholder="enter last name" id="TextBoxLastName" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <input type="button" value="Find Employee" id="empbutton" />
            <div class="col-xs-10" id="lblstatus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hello stranger!
Please, post the whole code or create a demo in https://jsfiddle.net/. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, that is essentially all the code, the only thing I've placed in menu.html, is the anchor to the modal. The only thing I've left out was <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> located in the </head> tag for Lab6.html

Comment: Here's an update for modal content in **Bootstrap 4**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934494/171456

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### **Update**

The way you're trying to get modal's content from another page is incorrect.

According to [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via
>   jQuery's load method and injected into the `.modal-content` div. If
>   you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href
>   attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown
>   below:
>
> ```
> <a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
> ```

So, firstly, you should change your `menu.html` file to be similar to the code above:

```
<li><a href="Lab6.html" data-target="#theModal" data-toggle="modal">Lab 6</a></li>
```

And then, part of your `Lab6.html` page must reside inside your `menu.html` page. E.g:

```
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="theModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, your `LAB6.html` would have only the code that was inside `.modal-content`. E.g:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
  <h1>Lab 6</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      Employee Information
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Title:</div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="title"></div>
        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">First:</div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="firstname"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Phone#</div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="phone"></div>
        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Email</div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="email"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Dept:</div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="departmentname"></div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-2">Surname:</div>
        <div class="text-left col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" placeholder="enter last name" id="TextBoxLastName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <input type="button" value="Find Employee" id="empbutton" />
      <div class="col-xs-10" id="lblstatus"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at [the plnkr I created for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7jDj2hORWmJ95c96qoG?p=preview).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, however the modal code is located in lab6.html. I edited my question for better clarification.

Comment: @Buzinas - How can I access particular modal if I have multiple modals in Lab6.html?

Comment: Idea of using modal through anchor tag is not working at all.

Comment: This solution is worked fine with Bootstrap 3.But I am not able to launch modal by using above procedure.Can you please tell how to implement with Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @ZohaIrshad check my answer

Answer (score 23):

Note that if you are using Bootstrap 4, the accepted answer does not work, because according to [Bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options)  about the `remote` option:

> **This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4.** We recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.
>
> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via jQuery's `load` method and injected into the `.modal-content` div. If you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the `href` attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below:
>
> ```
> <a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
> ```

To make it work, first remove the `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes from the link. You can leave the `href` attribute there.

```
<li><a href="Lab6.html" class='li-modal'>Lab 6</a></li>
```

Using jQuery we can add a click listener to the `<a>` element, but we do not want to directly go to the page indicated by the `href` attribute so we use `preventDefault()`. By simply using jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method we can load the content of the `lab6.html` page into `modal-content`.

```
$('.li-modal').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

[Full example here.](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/EjINpFlXJ1W6EZGz?preview)

Comment: I am getting this error on trying your solution: [Error] TypeError: '$('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load' is undefined).
Any ideas?