# How to open a bootstrap modal from another page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have on my Home.asp a login button which opens a modal. I have another page which has a login/logout button. How can I call the modal from Home page on this page.

Home. aspx Code:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#ModalCLogin" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Login</a></li>
```

Second page Code: (Here on this link click I want to call modal from Home.aspx)

```
<a href="#" data-target="#ModalCLogin" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Login</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I found a solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958219/getting-bootstraps-modal-content-from-another-page).
Let's say you have 2 pages,

- First.html  --> Contains an anchor to the modal
- Second.html --> Contains the definition of your modal

Basically you need to **href** the location of your modal in "Second.html" and **data-target** the id of your modal

```
<li><a href="Second.html" data-target="#theModal" data-toggle="modal">Lab 6</a></li>
```

Then still in your First.html you need to define the modal with the **id** until the **modal-content**

```
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="theModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

On the Second.html you define what is inside the **modal-content**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  ...
</div>
```

It worked for me. All the credits go to [Buzinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358027/buzinas) who answered this question on the link I provided above

Answer (score 1):

Calling the id of the modal in your other page.

Modal in your Home.aspx:

```
<div id="HomeModalId" data-width="500" data-backdrop="static"> Modal Content </Div>
```

In your second page, the link would be something like.

```
<a href="Home.aspx/#HomeModalId" data-target="#ModalCLogin" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Login</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first page:

```
 <a href="#" data-target="#ModalCLogin" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;Login</a></li>`
```

on the bottom of your first page:

```
<div id="ModalCLogin" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

on your 2nd pages:
"your modal"

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="ModalCLogin" class="myModal">
```