# How can i call a bootstrap modal from my main index.html page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have a index.html where my website resides  i searched on stackoverflow itself but the solution didnt work..i want to call a modal placed in my login.html here's my index.html code

```
<body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top " role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-Optio-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

              </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/Untitled-3-0.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-Optio-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="LightBoxForm.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#lightboxform" >Log In</a></li>
            <div id="lightboxform" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="500">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" role="button">Sign Up</a></li>


            </ul>



            </div>
        </div>




            </nav>
<body>
heres the declaration of files
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

code inside login.html........

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

PS:I DID THIS FOLLOWING [Getting Bootstrap's modal content from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958219/getting-bootstraps-modal-content-from-another-page)

Comment: This code above is kind of a mess what exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to load content from your login page into a modal on your index page?

Comment: I am trying to call a modal placed in my login.html from my index.html page.what i want is that modal code should be placed in some other html file and i should be able to login using button placed in my main index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-Optio-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>

            <li><a href=login.html class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button"  data-target=#myModal data-toggle="modal">Log In</a></li>

        <div class="modal fade text-center" id="theModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" role="button">Sign Up</a></li>


            </ul>

            </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: hi i have already used container-fluid class above it   updated my question with full body code of index,html for your refrence.