# BootStrap 4 Modal Content from another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to load a modal with content from another HTML file and have used both of these similar questions as references:
[Getting bootstrap modal content from another HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153222/getting-bootstrap-modal-content-from-another-html-file)

[Getting Bootstrap's modal content from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958219/getting-bootstraps-modal-content-from-another-page)

In my case, the modal is in the `home.html` and I want to load another file `contact.html` as the content into the modal

My Code:
Home.html

```
  <!-- NavBar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="navbar-brand" href="#">Land Power</span>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button class="signup btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" href="contact.html"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Contact.html

```
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <form action="email.php" method="post" target="iframe">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nameInput1">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="nameInput1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="emailInput1">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput1" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <iframe name="iframe" frameBorder="0" class="d-block mx-auto alert" role="alert"></iframe>
```

However I am having a similar issue to the one mentioned in the first post, where my modal is loading nothing and is just a thin white bar (empty modal). I am already running XAMPP as a server to localhost, and I don't see anything in my console as errors/warnings.
Additionally, this solution is for BootStrap 3 which the doc says the remote href is now depreciated.

So if I follow the second post (second solution which is updated for BS4) however and attempt to add these scripts (2 different functions that I found through other searches, I have tried both independently):

```
  <script>
    // $('.signup').on('click', function(e){
    //   e.preventDefault();
    //   $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    // });

    // $('.signup').on('click',function(){
    //   $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load('contact.html',function(){
    //         $('#theModal').modal({show:true});
    //     });
    // });
  </script>
```

I suffer the same problem as one of the commenters where I get this:
`[Error] TypeError:'$('...').modal('...').find('...').load' is not a function.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just a coding scrub and had sourced the wrong version of jquery (slim, which does not support ajax calls like .load()). Make sure to use the full version of jquery!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery to load the modal, then remove data-toggle and data-target from the signup button.  Also, I'd recommend storing the link in a different attribute as maybe something is wonky about using href.

```
<button class="signup btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" linkFile="contact.html">Sign Up</button>
```

```
  $('.signup').on('click', function(e){
    $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('linkFile'));
  });
```

Another option is maybe try to split up the 'show'.. although this is likely not the issue... but i think worth a try

```
  $('.signup').on('click', function(e){
    $('#theModal').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('linkFile'));
    $('#theModal').modal('show')
  });
```

Comment: Neither suggestions worked out for me

Comment: @Jeff Does home.html and contact.html reside in the same folder?

Comment: They do reside in the same directory, after some investigation, I found out, as per the error message suggests, that `$('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content')` returns a div.modal-content object which does not support a .load() method, which makes me think I'm simply calling either the wrong method name or calling the .load() method in the wrong place. But since I can't find much documentation on how to load content into a modal, I don't know where is the correct place to load content

Comment: @Jeff Hmm, if that;s the case then I would try to load into a hidden div like `$('#contact-hidden').load(...)`, and then append that to the modal content: `$('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').html($('#contact-hidden').html())`

Comment: That did not seem to work as well. It turns out, through more research, the script I was loading for jquery was the slim version which allegedly does not support ajax and therefore the .load() method was disabled. I have now swapped to the non-slim version, let me try again and get back to you

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED, it turned out I simply had the wrong jquery script sourced, and now even my original code works. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Jeff, OK cool... glad you got it figured out