# How to reset form validation alert and error message?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I need help. Because i'm using 1 modal for addRoom, editRoom, editImageRoom. I just want to ask if there is a way that if I close/x the modal. The data and the error message will be refresh/reset. Then when I click the other button that opens the modal. The data will be reset. so the errors and validation will not show anymore in other modal interface. Note* im using 1 modal only. I just hide the other field when I click for specific button.

I have 3 different buttons but the modal it open is only one, i just hide some field.

Add button

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addRoom()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add a room </a>
```

Edit Info Button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editImage('.$id.')"><img src="../images/rooms/'.$image.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="90px" height="105px"></a>
```

Edit Image Button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editRoom('.$id.')" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Here's the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_form" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="form" name="form" method="post" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="summary-errors alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                      </button>
                      <p>Errors list below: </p>
                      <ul></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="for_field">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-addon control-label"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="room_num" name="room_num" placeholder="Room Number" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-addon control-label"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></label>
                                <select type="text" class="form-control"  id="room_type" name="room_type" placeholder="Room Type">
                                <option value="">--Choose Room Type--</option>
                                <?php 
                                $select = "SELECT * FROM room_type";
                                $qry = mysql_query($select)or die(mysql_query());
                                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
                                    echo '<option value="'.$rows['room_type_id'].'" alt="'.$rows['room_type_description'].'">'.$rows['room_type_name'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-addon control-label"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="rate" name="rate" placeholder="Rate" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-addon control-label"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="caps" name="caps" placeholder="Capacity" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="for_image">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="show_image" class="form-group input-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div id="for_upload">
                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                           <div class="form-group input-group input-group-file" >
                           <label class="input-group-addon control-label"><i class="fa fa-image"></i></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <span class="btn btn-success btn-file">
                                <i class="icon wb-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" >
                              </span>
                            </span>
                          </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="" />
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <span align="left" id="loader"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Jquery

```
function addRoom()
{
    save_method = 'add';
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#form').formValidation('resetForm', true);
    $('#for_field').show();
    $('#for_image').hide();
    $('#for_upload').show();
    $('#modal_form').modal('show');
    $('.modal-title').text('Add new room');

}

// edit modal
function editRoom(u)
{
    save_method = 'update';
    $.ajax({
        url: "serverside/get/roomGet.php",
        data: "rId="+u,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status == 1)
            {
                $('#id').val(data.room_id);
                $('#room_num').val(data.room_num);
                $('#room_type').val(data.room_type_id);
                $('#rate').val(data.room_rate);
                $('#caps').val(data.room_capacity);
                $('#for_field').show();
                $('#for_upload').hide();
                $('#modal_form').modal('show');
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $('#form').formValidation('resetForm', true);
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Room No: '+data.room_num);
            }else{
                $('body').html(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
}

function editImage(u)
{
    save_method = 'update-image';
    $.ajax({
        url: "serverside/get/roomImageGet.php",
        data: "rId="+u,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status == 2)
            {
                $('#hide-field').hide();
                $('#id').val(data.room_id);
                $('#room_num').val(data.room_num);
                $('#for_field').hide();
                $('#for_image').show();
                $('#for_upload').show();
                $('#modal_form').modal('show');
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $('#form').formValidation('resetForm', true);
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Image');
                $('#show_image').html(data.source);
            }else{
                $('body').html(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have no problems in code. i just want to ask how to reset the modal so the data from 1 button(modal) will not conflict the button(modal). thats all! thanks! just give me more good suggestion thanks :)

Comment: ok sir. I'm sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please stop the SHOUTING, both in your tile and in the post. ALL CAPS text is harder to read and understand, and it's really rude and annoying. When you look at the main page of questions, you see none except yours in ALL CAPS, because it's not appropriate here. It's also not necessary to say you need help, because if you didn't you wouldn't be posting here. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages to better understand what is (and isn't) appropriate here. Thanks. (And instead of saying *sorry*, [edit] your post and ask it properly.)

Comment: I'm sorry! I already change it. Have nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to call the modal with jquery ajax then you really don't need the lengthy jquery show/hide code. Here is an example code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li><a href="modal-content.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal">Edit/Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="theModal" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

modal-content.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

You can use three different files for model or call the same modal by Ajax for all actions. Also, you can follow this link:  [Getting Bootstrap's modal content from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958219/getting-bootstraps-modal-content-from-another-page)